# HANA SQL not SQLScript: Pass a table type to a procedure

Tags: sql, business-objects, hana

I have created a stored procedure that accepts a table type. It's a complex type that is used to dynamically filter a calculation view. The procedure and table type look like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DynamicFilter
(
    it_filterOptions FilterTable
) LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
AS
BEGIN
    --Do stuff with filter table
END;

Table Type: FilterTable
-------------------------------------
| ColumnName    | Operator  | Value |
-------------------------------------
| ColumnA       | EQ        | 5     |
| ColumnB       | GT        | 10    |
-------------------------------------
```

Using Data Services, I need to be able to call that procedure and pass in value for it_filterOptions.

```
sql('SomeDataSource', 'CALL DynamicFilter(it_filterOptions => something?');
```

However, from Data Services, when I call that procedure, I'll be executing "SQL" instead of "SQLScript", because of the execution context. As such, I can't declare and build out local variables. Accordingly, I can't figure out how to build out my it_filterOptions variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way to achieve this:

Create global temporary table with the same structure "FilterTable". Change the procedure as follows and insert the data to that global temporary table before executing the procedure.

CREATE PROCEDURE DynamicFilter() LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT

AS

BEGIN

-- Access that global temporary table directly

--Do stuff with filter table

END;